# Set TLS extensions in Java (e.g. trusted_ca_keys)

Tags: ssl, java

I'm trying to figure out how to set the trusted_ca_keys extension in a JAVA 8 TLS client. Or even in general: how do I set any TLS extension using the standard JSSE library provided by Oracle? I don't want to use any third-party libraries like BouncyCastle.

This is how I set up my SSL client so far, without any extensions:

```
/**
 * Initializes the TLS client 
 * 
 * @param host The address of the TLS server to connect to
 * @param port The port of the TLS server to connect to
 */
public boolean initialize(Inet6Address host, int port) {
    super.initialize();

    try {
        /*
         * Setting the system property for the keystore and truststore via 
         * - System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", [filePath given as a String])
         * - System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", [filePath given as a String])
         * does not work in a JAR file since only getResourceAsStream works there (which on the other
         * hand only returns an InputStream, not a file resource). Thus use setSSLFactories()
         */
        SecurityUtils.setSSLContext(
                GlobalValues.EVCC_KEYSTORE_FILEPATH.toString(), 
                GlobalValues.EVCC_TRUSTSTORE_FILEPATH.toString(),
                GlobalValues.PASSPHRASE_FOR_CERTIFICATES_AND_KEYS.toString());

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        getLogger().debug("Creating socket to TLS server ...");
        setTlsSocketToServer((SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
        getLogger().debug("TLS socket to server created");
        setInStream(getTlsSocketToServer().getInputStream());
        setOutStream(getTlsSocketToServer().getOutputStream());

        /*
         * The EVCC shall support at least one cipher suite as listed below according to 
         * the standard. An implementer may decide to choose only one of them:
         * - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
         * - TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
         */
        String[] enabledCipherSuites = {
                "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", 
                "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" // this cipher suite should be avoided, ECDH does not support perfect forward secrecy
        };
        getTlsSocketToServer().setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledCipherSuites);

        // Set the supported TLS protocol
        String[] enabledProtocols = {"TLSv1.2"};
        getTlsSocketToServer().setEnabledProtocols(enabledProtocols);

        /*
         * The communication session setup timeout needs to be set here in case there is any problem with the
         * TLS handshake.
         * The timeout value will be overwritten with every new message being sent
         */
        getTlsSocketToServer().setSoTimeout(TimeRestrictions.V2G_EVCC_COMMUNICATION_SETUP_TIMEOUT);



        getLogger().debug("Starting TLS handshake ...");
        getTlsSocketToServer().startHandshake();
        getLogger().debug("TLS handshake finished");

        getLogger().info("TLS client connection established \n\t from link-local address " +
                          getClientAddress() + " and port " + getClientPort() + 
                          "\n\t to host " + host.getHostAddress() + " and port " + port);

        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        getLogger().error("TLS client connection failed (UnknownHostException)!", e);
    } catch (SSLHandshakeException e) {
        getLogger().error("TLS client connection failed (SSLHandshakeException)", e);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        getLogger().fatal("TLS client connection failed (SocketTimeoutException) due to session setup timeout", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        getLogger().error("TLS client connection failed (IOException)!", e);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        getLogger().fatal("NullPointerException while trying to set keystores, resource path to keystore/truststore might be incorrect");
    } 

    return false;
}
```

And here's, for the sake of completeness, the code for setSSLContext:

```
/**
 * Sets the SSLContext of the TLSServer and TLSClient with the given keystore and truststore locations as
 * well as the password protecting the keystores/truststores.
 * 
 * @param keyStorePath The relative path and filename for the keystore
 * @param trustStorePath The relative path and filename for the truststore
 * @param keyStorePassword The password protecting the keystore
 */
public static void setSSLContext(
        String keyStorePath, 
        String trustStorePath,
        String keyStorePassword) {
    KeyStore keyStore = SecurityUtils.getKeyStore(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
    KeyStore trustStore = SecurityUtils.getKeyStore(trustStorePath, keyStorePassword);

    try {
        // Initialize a key manager factory with the keystore
        KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();

        // Initialize a trust manager factory with the truststore
        TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());    
        trustFactory.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();

        // Initialize an SSL context to use these managers and set as default
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext); 
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyStoreException | 
            KeyManagementException e) {
        getLogger().error(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " occurred while trying to initialize SSL context");
    }    
}
```

So now I need to know where in the code above I can tell Java to use certain TLS extensions. I need 'trusted_ca_keys' and 'staus_request_v2' (the latter is for OCSP multi-stapling).

I also implemented the server and need to support these extensions in the server as well, but this code example should suffice I think.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Since this question is entirely about writing code, I think you may find a better response on Stack Overflow.

Comment: On another note, typically you would use keytool to add keys to a truststore which your application would then reference, which only contained the trusted keys.  On one last note, in TLS 1.3, the trusted_ca_keys extension is being depricated in favor for a different extension.

Comment: Oh, and it looks like OSCP Stapling is supported in JDK 9, not 8. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.htm#JSSEC-GUID-F069F4ED-DF2C-4B3B-90FB-F89E700CF21A  It specifically talks about stapling.